# Beaglebone not accessible through LAN?

Tags: beagle-bone

Since the day I bought it I always use ethernet over USB connection, now I need to use RJ45 LAN cable to connect Beaglebone from my laptop, but my laptop can't even detect LAN connection from it, what could go wrong? Do I need straight or crossover cable? Do I need to configure something first on my BeagleBone?

> UPDATE: Managed to connect it through Crossover cable and assign it IP
>   address by running DHCP server on my laptop.

[image]

> As seen above my laptop assign IP 169.254.223.76, but when I tried to
>   connect to that IP using puTTY it gives me connection refused.

[image]
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure it with a static ip address, and assign your laptop a (different) static ip address. [Here](http://derekmolloy.ie/set-ip-address-to-be-static-on-the-beaglebone-black/) is a link to a guide to setting a static ip address.